# How to Re-Run my ProgressBar after its completes hi activity?

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, calculator

I need help with this, I made this calculator, and a progressbar , i need it to when its finish so i can click again and run again, i didnt found a way to do that, and do the same with anothr data or the same data as well

```
 private TextView textResultado;
    private TextView editpeso;
    private TextView editaltura;
    private Button botao;
    private ProgressBar pb;
    private TextView txt;
    int i = 0;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    String[] mensagens = {"Preencha todos os campos!"};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        iniciar();

        botao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String peso = editpeso.getText().toString();
                String altura = editaltura.getText().toString();

                if (peso.isEmpty() || altura.isEmpty()) {
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, mensagens[0], Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    snackbar.setBackgroundTint(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                    snackbar.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                    snackbar.show();
                }




        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {calculadoramm(view);
                while (i < 100) {
                    i += 1;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(60);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            pb.setProgress(i);
                            txt.setText(i + "% Verificando...");
                         if (i == pb.getMax())
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Completo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        }).start();
    }
        });


    }


    private void iniciar() {

        textResultado = findViewById(R.id.textResultado);
        editpeso = findViewById(R.id.editpeso);
        editaltura = findViewById(R.id.editaltura);
        botao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botao);
        pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);


    }


    public void calculadoramm(View view) {

        double peso = Double.parseDouble(editpeso.getText().toString());
        double altura = Double.parseDouble(editaltura.getText().toString());
        double resultado = peso / (altura * altura);

        //Se

        if (resultado <= 18.5) {
            textResultado.setText("Abaixo do Peso!");
            textResultado.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright));

        }
        if (resultado <= 18.5 || resultado >= 24.9) {
            textResultado.setText("Peso normal!");
            textResultado.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_light));

        }
        if (resultado <= 25 || resultado >= 29.9) {
            textResultado.setText("Excesso de peso!");
            textResultado.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_light));


            if (resultado <= 30 || resultado >= 34.9) {
                textResultado.setText("Obesidade nivel I!");
                textResultado.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_orange_light));

                if (resultado <= 35 || resultado >= 39.9) {
                    textResultado.setText("Obesidade nivel II!");
                    textResultado.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light));

                    if (resultado >= 40) {
                        textResultado.setText("Obesidade nivel III ou Morbida!");
                        textResultado.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light));
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to add an Intent to start activity from Main to my results and None seems to work, and updated the code

Comment: can u put the xml file here?

Comment: sure, give me a second

Comment: hey i solved myself, i have anoher problem now